# Indexing problem with SOLR (MultiMaxScoreQParserPlugin)

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to integrate SOLR with Hybris but both of them are running on Kubernetes as a diffferent pod.

If I'm trying indexing SOLR on Hybris, it throws the error below;

```
ERROR [BackofficeLO-47] (000001JT) [SolrStandaloneSearchProvider] Error from server at http://10.10.100.181:34324/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'master_backoffice_backoffice_product_flip': Unable to create core [master_backoffice_backoffice_product_flip] Caused by: de.hybris.platform.solr.search.MultiMaxScoreQParserPlugin
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://10.10.100.181:34324/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'master_backoffice_backoffice_product_flip': Unable to create core [master_backoffice_backoffice_product_flip] Caused by: de.hybris.platform.solr.search.MultiMaxScoreQParserPlugin
```

I guess somethings wrong with SOLR "deafult" indexing directory.

Solr is running as process like below inside the pod;

```
solr@solr-fsd33wdf-qteg:/opt/solr-8.5.2$ ps -ef | grep solr
solr          10       1  0 Jun23 ?        00:15:55 /usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=250 -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xlog:gc*:file=/var/solr/logs/solr_gc.log:time,uptime:filecount=9,filesize=20M -Dsolr.jetty.inetaccess.includes= -Dsolr.jetty.inetaccess.excludes= -Dsolr.log.dir=/var/solr/logs -Djetty.port=8983 -DSTOP.PORT=7983 -DSTOP.KEY=solrrocks -Duser.timezone=UTC -Djetty.home=/opt/solr/server -Dsolr.solr.home=/var/solr/data -Dsolr.data.home= -Dsolr.install.dir=/opt/solr -Dsolr.default.confdir=/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/var/solr/log4j2.xml -Xss256k -Dsolr.jetty.https.port=8983 -jar start.jar --module=http
```

So default confdir is /opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf

If I'm check SOLR_HOME variable, it's different directory;

```
solr@solr-f575dcfdf-qtnpg:/opt/solr-8.5.2$ echo $SOLR_HOME
/var/solr/data
```

So, how can I change confdir to **/var/solr/data** ? I guess this is the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: how did you setup solr? is this a clean installation from scratch? or did you copy some items over from Hybris?

Comment: I'm just using solr Docker image from Docker Hub.

Comment: did you mount the customizations from hybris in you docker? (modules/search-and-navigation/solrserver/resources/solr/<version>/customizations) ?

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/1808/en-US/b6ffebf478cf4c41acf446a572ecbd8b.html#loio111e150e8c7b4494ba2e5e64f467c405) provides you with information on how to use the standalone setup.  The **ant configureSolrServer** takes an argument of the path to the original Solr binary that you should download from [here](https://solr.apache.org/downloads.html). This overwrites the files in the directory with the SAP Commerce specific setup.  The **MultiMaxScoreQParserPlugin** is part of **solr-hybris-components-<version_of_solr>.jar** file, where the <version_of_solr> corresponds to the solr version your SAP Commerce is running on.  Note that SAP Commerce also supports multiple Solr versions and it depends on what configuration you have.

You may then extend the default Solr docker image as provided [here](https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr/blob/master/README.md#extending-the-image) to have your setup running.